# List files modified on a particular date in hp unix

Tags: unix, hp-ux

How to list the files modified on 24th dec in a folder in hp unix.

I have a folder containing huge number of files, I just want to filter files modified on a particular date. Say december 15th..

Comment: Which programming language are you working in? Does it have a way to `opendir`/`readdir` and `stat`?

Comment: If a file was modified on the date in question, and then again on a later date, do you want it listed?  (If so, you are out of luck.)  Or are you looking for all files that were last modified on a particular date?  The latter is doable, the former is not unless you are using an obscure file system that stores the necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (not sure if what you need):

```
ll | grep 'Dec 15'
```

Comment: `ll` is probably an alias for `ls -l` or something similar, and it may or may not be defined.